# How to transform JSON to JSON using WSO2 XSLT mediator?

Tags: json, xml, xslt, wso2-esb

I was using  XSLT mediator inside WSO2 EI/ESB version 6.5.0.  I need to transform json to json , for that i thought of using XSLT mediator .

Input json as follows ,

```
 {
                "claim_type": [
                    {
                        "value": "Buildings",
                        "code": 1,
                        "effectiveDate": "1920-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "system": "POLICY"
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

Output json as follows ,  'value' will be transformed to 'description' and 'code' is transformed to 'id'

```
 "claim_type": [
                {
                    "description": "Buildings",
                    "id": 1,
                    
                }
              ]
            }
```

Tricky part  is 'claim_type' is not fixed , it can be any text'xxxxxxx' . Can i do it with XSLT code . Can some one please suggest hint for this ?

Comment: (1) You're expected to show an attempt as a [mcve] and ask about a specific programming impasse you've encountered.  (2) If no XML is involved, why use XSLT rather than JavaScript for JSON-to-JSON mapping?

Comment: thanks for the reponse . I am using tool which accepts XSLT as transformation mediator . Hence looking for XSLT solution for this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to address my point (1) above and include the name of the tool and especially the latest version of XSLT that it supports.  Thanks.

Comment: XSLT 3 has support for `json-to-xml` and `xml-to-json` and it also can of course transform the intermediary XML format, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsL. But the documentation of https://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/ only mentions XSLT 2 so you would have to check whether any proprietary functions exist for your platform to convert JSON to some XML the XSLT 2 can then transform and a proprietary function to convert XML back to JSON.

Comment: You may get more help if you post the XML that your tool produces from your input, and the XML that your tool expects in order to produce the JSON result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an example using a script mediator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="transformation"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https,local">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{
                    "claim_type": [
                        {
                            "value": "Buildings",
                            "code": 1,
                            "effectiveDate": "1920-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                            "system": "POLICY"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "Buildings2",
                            "code": 2,
                            "effectiveDate": "1920-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                            "system": "POLICY2"
                        }
                    ]
                }</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <script language="js">
                var claims = mc.getPayloadJSON();
                var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                var keys = Object.keys(claims);
                claims = claims[keys[0]];
                var response = {claims: []};
                for(var i =0; i < claims.length; i++) {
                    var item = claims[i];
                    response.claims.push({id: item.code, claim_type: item.value});
                }       
                mc.setPayloadJSON(response);
            </script>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="messageType"
                      scope="axis2"
                      type="STRING"
                      value="application/json"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <description/> 
</proxy>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this , look like this will work for me